# Lightbox next/prev images don't show up

Tags: lightbox

There's a lightbox but Previous/Next links do not show up. I've tried to play with z-index, removing :hover, etc., nothing seems to work. Am I missing something really obvious?

pictures itself are in the right place, and links do work, if you click at the right part of the image it takes you to the next one, etc., just pictures aren't shown

thanks in advance

Comment: can you inspect it with firebug(or something else?) and see if the url's to the images work or if something is displayed on top of it or any other strange things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Previous/Next do not show up & work, you must change this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').each(function(indx, element){
        $(element).lightBox();
    });
});
```

If you need Previous/Next only do not show up, you can use transparent picture for example.